# using log4j with hibernate and glassfish 3.0.1

Tags: java, hibernate, glassfish, log4j

I'm trying to setup hibernate 3.5.3 with JPA on glassfish 3.0.1;

I'm using a netbeans 6.9.1 enterprise project; I added all the required hibernate files and everything is fine except logging...

I added to the project classpath like the docs say the following (only the log related jars listed):

-slf4j-api-1.5.8.jar

-slf4j-log4j12-1.5.8.jar

-log4j-1.2.16.jar

-log4j.properties which looks like:

```
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

log4j.rootLogger=info, stdout

log4j.logger.org.hibernate.test=info
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl=debug
```

I also activated debug using `-Dlog4j.debug` JVM property.

As soon as I deploy I get this in the server log:

```
SEVERE: log4j:ERROR A "org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender" object is not assignable to a "org.apache.log4j.Appender" variable.
SEVERE: log4j:ERROR The class "org.apache.log4j.Appender" was loaded by 
SEVERE: log4j:ERROR [EarLibClassLoader : 
urlSet = [URLEntry : file:/C:/Users/Bogdan/Documents/NetBeansProjects/GwtCms/dist/gfdeploy/GwtCms/lib/antlr-2.7.6.jar, URLEntry : file:/C:/Users/Bogdan/Documents/NetBeansProjects/GwtCms/dist/gfdeploy/GwtCms/lib/commons-collections-3.1.jar, URLEntry : file:/C:/Users/Bogdan/Documents/NetBeansProjects/GwtCms/dist/gfdeploy/GwtCms/lib/dom4j-1.6.1.jar, URLEntry : file:/C:/Users/Bogdan/Documents/NetBeansProjects/GwtCms/dist/gfdeploy/GwtCms/lib/gwt-servlet.jar, URLEntry : file:/C:/Users/Bogdan/Documents/NetBeansProjects/GwtCms/dist/gfdeploy/GwtCms/lib/hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.0.Final.jar, URLEntry : file:/C:/Users/Bogdan/Documents/NetBeansProjects/GwtCms/dist/gfdeploy/GwtCms/lib/hibernate3.jar, URLEntry : file:/C:/Users/Bogdan/Documents/NetBeansProjects/GwtCms/dist/gfdeploy/GwtCms/lib/javassist-3.9.0.GA.jar, URLEntry : file:/C:/Users/Bogdan/Documents/NetBeansProjects/GwtCms/dist/gfdeploy/GwtCms/lib/jta-1.1.jar, URLEntry : file:/C:/Users/Bogdan/Documents/NetBeansProjects/GwtCms/dist/gfdeploy/GwtCms/lib/log4j-1.2.16.jar, URLEntry : file:/C:/Users/Bogdan/Documents/NetBeansProjects/GwtCms/dist/gfdeploy/GwtCms/lib/slf4j-api-1.5.8.jar, URLEntry : file:/C:/Users/Bogdan/Documents/NetBeansProjects/GwtCms/dist/gfdeploy/GwtCms/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.5.8.jar]
doneCalled = false 
 Parent -> org.glassfish.internal.api.DelegatingClassLoader@10ab6fa
] whereas object of type 
SEVERE: log4j:ERROR "org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender" was loaded by [EarLibClassLoader : 
urlSet = [URLEntry : file:/C:/Users/Bogdan/Documents/NetBeansProjects/GwtCms/dist/gfdeploy/GwtCms/lib/antlr-2.7.6.jar, URLEntry : file:/C:/Users/Bogdan/Documents/NetBeansProjects/GwtCms/dist/gfdeploy/GwtCms/lib/commons-collections-3.1.jar, URLEntry : file:/C:/Users/Bogdan/Documents/NetBeansProjects/GwtCms/dist/gfdeploy/GwtCms/lib/dom4j-1.6.1.jar, URLEntry : file:/C:/Users/Bogdan/Documents/NetBeansProjects/GwtCms/dist/gfdeploy/GwtCms/lib/gwt-servlet.jar, URLEntry : file:/C:/Users/Bogdan/Documents/NetBeansProjects/GwtCms/dist/gfdeploy/GwtCms/lib/hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.0.Final.jar, URLEntry : file:/C:/Users/Bogdan/Documents/NetBeansProjects/GwtCms/dist/gfdeploy/GwtCms/lib/hibernate3.jar, URLEntry : file:/C:/Users/Bogdan/Documents/NetBeansProjects/GwtCms/dist/gfdeploy/GwtCms/lib/javassist-3.9.0.GA.jar, URLEntry : file:/C:/Users/Bogdan/Documents/NetBeansProjects/GwtCms/dist/gfdeploy/GwtCms/lib/jta-1.1.jar, URLEntry : file:/C:/Users/Bogdan/Documents/NetBeansProjects/GwtCms/dist/gfdeploy/GwtCms/lib/log4j-1.2.16.jar, URLEntry : file:/C:/Users/Bogdan/Documents/NetBeansProjects/GwtCms/dist/gfdeploy/GwtCms/lib/slf4j-api-1.5.8.jar, URLEntry : file:/C:/Users/Bogdan/Documents/NetBeansProjects/GwtCms/dist/gfdeploy/GwtCms/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.5.8.jar]
doneCalled = false 
 Parent -> org.glassfish.internal.api.DelegatingClassLoader@91cd46
].
SEVERE: log4j:ERROR Could not instantiate appender named "stdout".
SEVERE: log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.Version).
SEVERE: log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
SEVERE: log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
```

Any ideas on how do I fix this? Thank you!

**EDIT**

I tried to remove log4j from my project as  Tushar Tarkas suggested:

```
SEVERE: org/apache/log4j/Level
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log4j/Level
        at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getSingleton(LoggerFactory.java:223)
        at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.bind(LoggerFactory.java:120)
        at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.performInitialization(LoggerFactory.java:111)
        at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory(LoggerFactory.java:269)
```

**EDIT2: SOLUTION**

I don't know why, but if I copy log4j-1.2.16.jar file in /domains/domain1/lib it's working.

**EDIT3:**

Pascal, here's what GF deploys.

```
EnterpriseApplication1-ejb_jar >
    .netbeans_automatic_build
    .netbeans_update_resources
    ejbs // classes for EJB
    entities // classes for entities
    log4j.properties
    META-INF
EnterpriseApplication1-war_war >
    index.jsp
    META-INF
    WEB-INF
META-INF
lib >
    antlr-2.7.6.jar
    commons-collections-3.1.jar
    dom4j-1.6.1.jar
    hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.0.Final.jar
    hibernate3.jar
    javassist-3.9.0.GA.jar
    jta-1.1.jar
    log4j-1.2.16.jar
    slf4j-api-1.5.8.jar
    slf4j-log4j12-1.5.8.jar
```

Comment: Removing log4j.jar is certainly not a solution. But I'd like to know how you package it exactly.

Comment: Anyway, I've written a tutorial about setting up Hibernate + GF + NB. I'm still interested in a better way of making log4j work with GF3. The tutorial can be found here: http://bogdantanaseit.blogspot.com/2010/08/hibernate-jpa-20-on-glassfish-v3-with.html

Answer (score 2):

I could find some discussions related to similar problem. The problem is with glassfish version 3 and above. The classes seem to be loaded by different class loaders.

Check [this](http://old.nabble.com/log4j-configured-app-fails-in-glassfish-v4-td27052459.html).

Comment: Thanks for the input. I've looked through that discussion but they didn't seem to get to a resolution. Any idea if I can set "something" in glassfish or log4j to fix this?

Comment: Try removing log4j's jar file from your applications lib directory. GlassFish already has log4j which it uses internally.

Comment: This problem could arise if there are 2 log4js with different version. See this (http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-77688.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use application-specific classloading with Glassfish.

Place the log4j.jar into
[Glassfish-Install-Dir].[PATH-TO-DOMAIN]/lib/applibs.
You can also make a new directory to keep things clean:
[Glassfish-Install-Dir].[PATH-TO-DOMAIN]/lib/applibs/MY_APPLICATIONS_DEPENDENCIES

After you have done that you have to specify to load log4j when you deploy your application.
There are two options:
1. Admin console / web interface: fill in the information for log4j in the option liberaries
2. Use the asadmin deploy command with the ----libraries option and specify comma-separated paths. For details, see the Oracle GlassFish Server 3.1-3.1.1 Reference Manual. (cited from Oracle GlassFish Server 3.1 Application Development Guide)

Comment: You no longer deploy log4j.jar with your application.